# How to run EXPLAIN / ANALYSE on a running query?

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, explain

I have a very complex query running in PostgreSQL. It uses multiple tables with randomly generated names. These temp tables are dropped at the end of execution. Obviously, I can't use EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN ANALYSE on tables which don't exist anymore.

Is there any way to execute EXPLAIN / EXPLAIN ANALYSE on running queries? i.e Whilst I know the temporary tables exist?

Comment: you cant - but you can just add the explain / explain analyze before your query

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the query. It's generated by a third party system. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You could install the [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) extension

Comment: The question is very old but comes out near the top of Google Search, so I thought it'd be useful to provide an useful answer: try https://github.com/StarfishStorage/explain-running-query